# Cisco Nexus 9K route-map match interface regular expressions

Tags: nx-os, route-map

I'm using a 9504 running 7.0(3)I7(3). I'm trying to configure a route-map that matches all of my VLAN interfaces:

```
route-map RedistribInterfaces permit 10
myrouter(config-route-map)# match interface vlan ?
  <1-4094>  Vlan interface number
  regex     Interface regex
```

So far I can't find any regex syntax that it will accept. Examples I've tried:

```
match interface vlan regex [0-9]+
match interface vlan regex ^[0-9]+
match interface vlan regex ^[0-9]+$
```

And about a thousand other variants.

Comment: May I ask what protocol you're trying to redistribute into?

Comment: In this case BGP but I think it would be about the same in EIGRP as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access Configuration Mode:
Enter privileged EXEC mode by typing enable and provide the necessary credentials. Then, enter global configuration mode:

```
myrouter> enable
myrouter# configure terminal
```

Create a Route Map:
Create a route map and specify a sequence number. In this example, we'll use sequence number 10:

```
myrouter(config)# route-map RedistribInterfaces permit 10
```

Match VLAN Interfaces using Regular Expression:
Use the match interface vlan regex command with the appropriate regular expression to match VLAN interfaces with numbers:

```
myrouter(config-route-map)# match interface vlan regex .*[0-9]+.*
```

.* at the beginning and end of the regular expression allows any number of characters before and after the VLAN number.
[0-9]+ matches one or more digits.
This regular expression will match any VLAN interface with a number in it. Adjust the regex according to your VLAN interface naming convention.
Apply the Route Map:
Apply the created route map to the desired configuration. For example, if you want to apply it to a route redistribution:

```
myrouter(config)# router ospf 1
myrouter(config-router)# redistribute connected route-map RedistribInterfaces
```

Validate and Save Configuration:
Validate your configuration and ensure that the regular expression is working as expected. Use the show run command to see the applied route-map configuration.

If everything looks correct, save the configuration changes:

```
myrouter# copy running-config startup-config
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Nguyen, it didn't occur to me to prefix and suffix with the wildcard - your answer was very helpful.